# Inverse Kinematics Chain Length Goes Down Wrong Branch

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

Trying to follow CG Geek's tutorial for making a tree rigged with inverse kinematics, however when I increase the chain length instead of progressing towards the trunk it instead goes back up a different branch.

[image: Length3]
[image: Length5]

Attached here are the photos of chain length 3 and 5, every other branch I tried with works perfectly fine and goes toward the trunk.

Mega link for the file:
https://mega.nz/file/eRlylQYa#yklLZUgpOwO9LQ7dWi95fLkDy0NpJc2d43LofkGw-OU

Comment: Check the parenting of your bones.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch the viewport display of the armature to *Octahedral* and hide the tree, you find that 4 bones back from the bone you're adding IK to the order of bones is switched:

[image: The IK chain followed back]

The IK chain is following the direction of bone parenting but you have Bone.41's parent be Bone.08 rather than Bone.40:

[image: Bone.41's parent is Bone.08]

You need to redo that part of the chain so that the bones are properly parented.